# SSIS Error - Parsing Query from SQL Task Fails Due to 80040153, Invalid Value for Registry

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssis-2017, execute-sql-task

## Problem Statement

I have a lot of SQL Server environments locally.

When trying to parse a SQL task with very basic `truncate table dbo.table` syntax, I get the following error message.

I should note that when I execute the task it works fine despite throwing an error when parsed.

My understanding is that it's related to a corrupt .ddl file at the 'Microsoft SQL Server/1XX/DTS/Binn/'
- having trouble determining which SQL Server version's components be the cause.

Is there a way of determining the corrupt .dll and reconciling this issue?

### Error Message

```
------------------------------

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {dummy123-dum1-dum2-dum3-dummyds2309}
failed due to the following error: 80040153 Invalid value for registry 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040153 (REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE)).
```

## What I've Tried

Tested on Visual Studio 2017/2019

**Figuring out What Com Object is the Problem**

Because the message only gives me the CLSID I'm having trouble locating the actual com object it's referencing.

I've run `reg query HKCR\CLSID /s /f "{<CLSID>}"`
This confirmed that it isn't there, but that wasn't helpful.

**Environment**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.4.1 VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.1+29609.76 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03752 **Installed Version: Enterprise**
- SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.61912.09160  Microsoft SQL Server Data
  Tools
- SQL Server Integration Services   15.0.1900.80 Microsoft SQL Server
  Integration Services Designer Version 15.0.1900.80
- SsmsVsIntegration   1.0  Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions
  (Preview)   1.0 View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual
  Studio.

Comment: I have not run into that issue myself. What I would confirm is that the thrown error isn't masking something else. Like invalid query can throw some quirky error messages if you do it very wrongly. Quick check would be to change your query to something trivial like `SELECT 1` assuming a SQL Server source.

Comment: Thanks for the thought on this. It still threw the error message when parsing unfortunately. You gave me the idea to 'execute task' and see if it would work and it did despite not parsing. Noting that above

Comment: @RayJohnson Was this ever figured out?

Comment: @MaxB unfortunately, I do not recall it being fixed - it may warrant deletion since it's gone with no answers this long. Are you running into this error?